# Google Play Console _You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, google-play-console

when I load the bundle app on google play console, I get this error:

***You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service, or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without the 'android: exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See [developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported)***

This is my androidManifest.xml file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.typi">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"/>
   <application
        android:label="Blabi"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
           android:value="my secret key"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

As I understand I had to add android:exported="true" under the activities, I did that but the error is still there.

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong and how I can fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by updating the package `flutter_local_notifications` to the latest version.

Comment: You saved my day Man. Hats Off!

Answer (score 1):

`android:exported`
This element sets whether the activity can be launched by components of other applications:

If `"true"`, the activity is accessible to any app, and is launchable by its exact class name.

If `"false"`, the activity can be launched only by components of the same application, applications with the same user ID, or privileged system components. This is the default value when there are no intent filters.

In your case

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"

            android:exported="true"<!--Could be true or false-->

            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this doesn't work...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig' property 'buildConfigPackageName'.
   > Failed to query the value of property 'packageName'.
      > org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/Gabriele/AndroidStudioProjects/Typi/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml; lineNumber: 29; columnNumber: 56;